# Read the top 10 rows from the database

Tags: mysql

I have this small project I have been working on. I have a MySQL table that looks kind of like this

```
+---------+-------------+------+
| Content | Date Posted | Name |
+---------+-------------+------+
| Content | Date Posted | Name |
+---------+-------------+------+
```

And I need a PHP script to read the top 10 rows from the database, based on date posted.

Comment: @Pekka I need a PHP script that reads the table.

Comment: @ahnonorstudent well, that is a pretty basic task. I'd say pick a database wrapper of your choice (I'd recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) and work through the basic examples. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495277/where-can-i-find-an-introduction-to-using-pdo) is a nice PDO tutorial.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @Pekka , @KyleWpppd Thanks a lot. I read both and I find that the PDO suggestion is good. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHPMyAdmin to create tables, or run a script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Contents (
  Content MEMO NOT NULL,
  DatePosted DATE NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL);
```

and select the newest 10 like this:

```
SELECT
  t.Content,
  t.DatePosted,
  t.Name
FROM
  Contents t
ORDER BY
  DatePosted DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But while the answer seems small, it is actually a big question. Do you have no idea whatsoever? Maybe you should start by reading some tutorials if you don't want to get stuck every time you need a little something from your database.

Comment: sorry, I was to lazy to think of something. And I was really, really tired and I'm not used to MySQL. It is kinda new for me.