# What is the best choice for a simple cms system used for php websites

Tags: php, content-management-system

I would like to know what I can offer to clients when they want their existing website modified and want to update some off the content themselves?

It would give me more advantage because hosting party's are offering this also, thank you.

**EDIT**

**I voted myself also for closing it.**
It is to broad, I get it.
But You can still mention a couple of names that are really really simple before this topic will be closed!

Richard

Comment: Depends on what they want to update, there are thousand of PHP scripts that create websites based on files on disk and a mysql database. I'd say your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wordpress

In a few words : Simply because no other CMS stands out like that, especially for your target group. By far the simplest solution **for clients** (that's what I'm suggesting them too, and they seldom have any problem getting used to it).

It's easy to use and get the handle of it fast, plus after you show them a bit around, they seem to be feeling at ease (ok, unless you delve into more hardcore stuff that is... :-))

**Reasons :**

- Users can easily edit/add content themselves
- Tons of plugins to extend initial functionality according to clients' needs (you know all these : "how about if we added X, Y, Z...?" lol)

---

*Another take on the same subject : http://www.dmsqd.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/the-best-cms-tool-finding-the-best-website-cms-for-your-clients/*

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this, both reasons given here are not exclusive to Wordpress. #1 is the definition of a CMS, and #2 applies to any CMS worth its salt.

Answer (score 0):

Very subjective question.  I would recommend basing your choice on the core content:

### e-Commerce

- Magento
- osCommerce
- ZenCart

### Blogging

- Wordpress (arguably stands alone)

### General / Jack-of-all-trades

- Drupal
- Joomla (I don't like it personally, but to each his/her own)
- PyroCMS
- ExpressionEngine
- ModX
- Concrete5

I don't know if there's already a community wiki post for this type of question.  References anyone?

**EDIT:**

This is a very common question.  Here are some related resources:

- [What is a good PHP CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450852/what-is-a-good-php-cms)
- [What is the "best" free CMS for my needs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618685/what-is-the-best-free-cms-for-my-needs)
- [Simple CMS mySQL / PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928370/simple-cms-mysql-php)

Comment: Using Wordpress and Magento will ensure a future revenue stream if the client ever manages to attract more than 3 concurrent users. (cmsmatrix.org publishes comparisons of functionality - but doesn't reveal much about performance).

Comment: That's a little misleading.  You can do a lot with a reverse proxy cache.

Comment: No. You can only do a little with a standard wordpress install. OTOH if you use an ESI plugin and ESI assembly on the proxy then it makes quite a big difference - but Facebook won't be losing any sleep.

Comment: Because of WP's community, there have been entire seminars devoted to scaling it.  It's not as hard as you make it sound, nor is it as common as a need.  BTW, I've completely abandoned using WP as a CMS, so this little discussion is hardly for my benefit.